# Name for a slightly-stronger than Nash Equilibrium?

Tags: game-theory

As I understand it, a Nash Equilibrium is a fixed point in strategy profile space, in the sense that it is not to any individual player's advantage to deviate from said strategy profile.

Is there a name for the (slightly stronger) equilibrium condition whereby it is to every individual player's disadvantage to deviate from said strategy profile? If so, what is it?

Comment: (@Silverfish, FWIW, note that you can link to other SE sites by enclosing the <name.SE> in square brackets `[economics.SE]` [economics.SE].)

Comment: @Silverfish [math.SE] also has both those tags.

Comment: @Glen_b I should have thought of that. The very verbal description reminded me a lot of some of the game theory posts on [economics.SE] but I imagine it would fit in well at either site. I'm not sure if it would be a dupe at Math.SE but I did have a quick check when I made the suggestion and am pretty sure it isn't at Econ.SE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a strict Nash Equilibrium.